# Determine the singular points of the following function and explain why the function is analytic everywhere except at those points:

Tags: complex-analysis

Determine the singular points of the following function and explain why the function is analytic everywhere except at those points:

$ f(z)= \exp ( \frac{z^3+i}{z^2−3z+2)})$

I need help with this exercise. can you detail it step by step? it's from a practice form. I thank you infinitely.

Comment: Compositions of analytic functions are analytic. Rational functions are analytic except where the denominator is $0$. That is all you need to know for this.

Answer (score 0):

$f(z)= \exp(\frac{z^3+i}{z^2−3z+2)})$

This function has singularity only where denominator of fraction is zero, that too will have  essential singularity only,elsewhere it is analytic.
$ f(z) = \exp(\frac{f_1(z)}{f_2(z)})$
has singularity only on zeros of $f_2(z)$.

In your problem $f_2(z)$ is polynomial $({z^2−3z+2)}$.

simply find zeros of this, they will be only possible singularity in C(not including infinity)